# Migrating an existing iPhone app to iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have an iPhone app that is quite mature and we are planing to go ahead with an iPad app. The iPad app will contain features which are exclusive to the iPad. Is the best way to create an universal app or to maintain two separate projects. If I maintain two projects, do I still have a way to share code between the two projects?. Any information would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the two versions are very much alike, I'd say create a universal app and give the iPad version its own `view controllers` and/or `views` to create a different interface for that device. You will have to make your code check for which device it runs on for certain methods, but I bet most of your logic just translates well to the big screen. I do the same and it is fun to have it all in one project.

If you do want to split it into two projects, you can add common classes and resources by adding them by reference and only editing them from one central place. This way, changes made in that central project are automatically available in the project that references those resources. I do this for example for an image editing class that I share between projects.

Comment: Thanks Richard, definitely got a better understanding about the two approaches.